# Conditional security() call

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get the daily `High/Low/Close` with a `security()` call (with `lookahead_on`).
Those daily `hlc` values remain unchanged for every intraday bar within the same day.
Therefore, I'm trying to call the `security` function only once per day (when the date changes).
However, I keep getting the error `Cannot read property 'isTuple' of undefined`.
I don't understand why, and cannot seem to get it fixed.
Any ideas?

This is my example code

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

f_sec() => security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [high,low,close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

bar_date_ts = timestamp(year(time),month(time),dayofmonth(time),0,0,0)
is_new_date = change(bar_date_ts)

var float h = na
var float l = na
var float c = na

if (is_new_date)
    [x,y,z] = f_sec()
    h := x
    l := y
    c := z
    
plot(h)
plot(l)
plot(c)
```

Comment: Update: This bug has been resolved by an internal update of Pine Script. The original script works fine now, without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security function should be called in the global scope.

If you'll remove the tuple you'll receive the correct compiler error:
`Cannot call 'security' or 'financial' inside 'if' or 'for'`

```
if (is_new_date)
    x := security(syminfo.ticker, "D", high, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    y := security(syminfo.ticker, "D", low, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    z := security(syminfo.ticker, "D", close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    h := x
    l := y
    c := z
```

So move your f_sec function outside the if statement, however the function would be called on each bar instead of once per day.

The solution is to use the conditional operator `? :`, it doesn't work with tuples, so you'll have to make 3 security calls. Also Im not sure about saving the computation power that way, compiler could evaluate both.

```
var float x = na
var float y = na
var float z = na

x := is_new_date ? security(syminfo.ticker, "D", high,  lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) : nz(x[1])
y := is_new_date ? security(syminfo.ticker, "D", low,   lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) : nz(y[1])
z := is_new_date ? security(syminfo.ticker, "D", close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) : nz(z[1])

plot(x)
plot(y)
plot(z)
```

Note that using `lookahead` without `history reference operator` will lead script to repaint during current security resolution argument period.

Comment: This bug has been resolved by an internal update of Pine Script. The original script works fine now, without throwing an error. Thanks for the workaround though. I've been using that workaround in the meantime.